# JQuery LightSlider inside Bootstrap pills

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery lightSlider as image slider. I want to have sliders inside bootstrap pills (one slider per pill). Nevertheless, I have found the following situation: In the first pill the slider is OK. In the second pill the slider content is not displayed (resizing the window brings up the slider content!). I don't see how to solve this problem. Any help will be sincerely appreciated.

My (simplified) html:

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"> <a data-toggle="pill" id="pill1" href="#s1">Pill 1</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a data-toggle="pill" id="pill2" href="#s2">Pill 2</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="col-md-12 tab-pane fade in active" id="s1">
        <ul id="slider-1">
            <li>
                <p>one</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>two</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>tree</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 tab-pane fade active" id="s2">
        <ul id="slider-2">
            <li>
                <p>uno</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>dos</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>tres</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
function initSlider(sliderId) {
  $('#'+sliderId).lightSlider({
    item:2,
    loop:false,
    slideMove:1
  });
}

initSlider('slider-1');     
initSlider('slider-2');
```

And the Jsfiddle reproducing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/sedtjchs/4/

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**: You are trying to call `lightSlider` on the content(`#s2`) which was already hidden so plugin can not calculate  height, width(and etc) on that element.

Add `active` class to the second `.panel-pane`.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sedtjchs/6/)

Comment: Thanks Safian for your solution. Nevertheless, it has a "little" problem. At initialization, the content of the second pill is present (hidden) in the first one: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sedtjchs/9/)

Comment: @DianaMoreno I am sorry to replay late. You can solve your problem by giving a fixed width to `.tab-content`(For example: `width:55px`). Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sedtjchs/10/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {

    $('#slider-2').lightSlider({
        item:4,
        loop:false,
        slideMove:2,
        pager: false,
        easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1)',
        speed:600,
        responsive : [

            {
                breakpoint:480,
                settings: {
                    item:2,
                    slideMove:1
                }
            }
        ]
    }).refresh();
});
```

Comment: Please write a description above your code, so others can understand what you did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but the Alex's solution doesn't work for me as my tab wrapper doesn't have a fixed height so it will show blank gap under the 1st tab at the first load.

The Thành Nguyễn's solution is working for me. Basically it's refreshing the slider everytime you click on the tab navigation, so then LightSlider will be able to calculate the active container height.

Here's the complete script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        $('#slider-2').lightSlider({
            item:4,
            loop:false,
            slideMove:2,
            pager: false,
            easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1)',
            speed:600,
            responsive : [

                {
                    breakpoint:480,
                    settings: {
                        item:2,
                        slideMove:1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }).refresh();
    });
});
```